# Issue with MapTypeControlOptions in Google Maps API v3 with Google Earth Plugin enabled

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth-plugin

I am using the Google Maps API V3 with the Google Earth Plugin enabled. I am trying to display four options for map views (terrain, satellite, satellite with labels (a.k.a. hybrid), and earth.

With the last line commented out (google earth plugin not enabled) everything works correctly. When the last line is in place the 'mapTypeControlOptions' are all ignored. In this case I am just trying to specify the mapTypes, but if I specify anything else in that block it is ignored as well.

Is there a workaround for this or am I screwing something up? I've played around with it for several days and am not seeing what I could possibly be mixing up. Live example of this with the rest of the context can be found at: http://grandlin.es:5000

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.797, -105.776),
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE] 
    }
});

//var googleEarth = new GoogleEarth(map);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Had downgrade to the API V2 even though it will stop working in 4 months... Hopefully between now and then they come up with a solution. Even their newly released documentation uses the V2 API...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using this instead of var googleEarth = .....

map.addMapType(G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP);

For an example of how this is used view the source on this page.

http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/mapsapi/index.html

Comment: Thanks, but that appears to only work for Google Maps API V2. I may just need to use that older API if I can't find a solution for the current one.

Comment: Do not use API V2, it is deprecated. The V2 API will stop working on May 19, 2013.

Comment: That's the main reason I don't want to. But it seems like this isn't possible from what I've seen in the V3 API. Which seems kind of outrageous.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [google-maps-utility-library](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/).

See the page on [Google Earth API for Google Maps v3](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/docs/reference.html).

There is even a basic working example of maps/earth integration, that allows you to toggle between MAP, SATELLITE, EARTH.

See: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/examples/earth.html

Comment: unless I'm being thick (which is entirely possible) the example you linked to doesn't do what it says on the tin. I've seen this with some of the other google examples, a bunch of them just don't work any more, probably due to API changes made later.

Comment: yep, I am being thick, didn't have the google earth web plugin installed. ignore my last :)